# Fastest livereloader sass into css (Grunt, Gulp - Browsersync )

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, gulp, frontend, browser-sync

I am looking for fastest livereload result (sass into css + browerssync)

Grunt or Gulp is better fastest result?

I was experimenting with Grunt, 
When save css file we get livereload without nothing delay but when sass compile sass into css its working with 1 or 2 seconds delay

This is my grunt code

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    watch: {
      sass: {
        files: "app/scss/*.scss",
        tasks: "sass:dev"
      }
    },
    sass: {
      dev: {
        files: {
          "app/css/styles.css": "app/scss/styles.scss"
        }
      }
    },
    browserSync: {
      default_options: {
        bsFiles: {
          src: [
            "css/*.css",
            "*.html"
          ]
        },
        options: {
          watchTask: true,
          proxy: "yourvhost.dev"
        }
      }
    }
  });

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-sass');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browser-sync');

  // Launch BrowserSync + watch task
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['browserSync', 'watch']);
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Gulp has traditionally been a bit quicker since it uses node streams. A more in-depth read about the node stream subject and the Gulp/Grunt compiling of Sass you find [here](http://jaysoo.ca/2014/01/27/gruntjs-vs-gulpjs/).

edit: if you're thinking of using Grunt, you should check out grunt-sass. Seems to be the fastest one and pretty close to the Gulp one.